# Point subdomain to directory on same server with NGINX

Tags: nginx

The desired effect is to have `domain.com` proxy pass to `localhost:5000` and `sub.domain.com` proxy pass to `localhost:5000/sites/app`. Here is the server block for my sub domain.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/sites/app;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

When I type `sub.domain.com` into the browser it redirects me to `sub.domain.com/sites/app`. I do not want /sites/app showing in the browser URL bar.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding a `/` to the end. `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/sites/app/;`